# Why isn't my legend showing?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Why isn't my legend showing up when I plot this?

```
ggplot(data=baseline_total, aes(x=sighd_rater_total, color="sighd_rater_total")) + 
geom_area(stat="bin", col = 'light blue', fill='light blue') + 
geom_freqpoly(data=baseline_total,aes(x=sighd_tier1_total, color="sighd_tier1_total"), stat = "bin", col = 'dark blue')
```

Comment: [How to make a great R reproducible example?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269)

Comment: Get rid off the `""` in `aes()`.

Comment: Alternatively consider making use of the `aes_string`. Please also consider providing some data and redoing your example on some of the easily available data sets.

Comment: @beetroot, pls post your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

If you specify the colour (or fill, shape, etc.) within the `aes()` you need to do so without `""` in order to get a legend based on that variable.
So this will probably work:

```
ggplot(data = baseline_total, aes(x = sighd_rater_total, colour = sighd_rater_total)) + 
geom_area(stat="bin", colour = "light blue", fill = "light blue") + 
geom_freqpoly(data = baseline_total, aes(x = sighd_tier1_total, colour = sighd_tier1_total), stat = "bin")
```